# Writing jQuery or Javascript inside Angular to extend functionality

Tags: angularjs

Building Angular application to handle some custom url logic, but I'm not sure how I would build this into angular.

I have two jsfiddles I'll include the source code here.

```
<select class="kv">
<!-- ngRepeat: n in get.evoltage --><option ng-repeat="n in get.evoltage" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="230">230</option><!-- end ngRepeat: n in get.evoltage --><option ng-repeat="n in get.evoltage" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="460">460</option><!-- end ngRepeat: n in get.evoltage -->
</select>

<select class="khp">
    <!-- ngRepeat: n in get.ehp --><option ng-repeat="n in get.ehp" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="20">20</option><!-- end ngRepeat: n in get.ehp --><option ng-repeat="n in get.ehp" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="25">25</option><!-- end ngRepeat: n in get.ehp --><option ng-repeat="n in get.ehp" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="30">30</option><!-- end ngRepeat: n in get.ehp --><option ng-repeat="n in get.ehp" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="40">40</option><!-- end ngRepeat: n in get.ehp --><option ng-repeat="n in get.ehp" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="50">50</option><!-- end ngRepeat: n in get.ehp --><option ng-repeat="n in get.ehp" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="75">75</option><!-- end ngRepeat: n in get.ehp --><option ng-repeat="n in get.ehp" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="100">100</option><!-- end ngRepeat: n in get.ehp -->     
</select>
<div  id="buynow-kore" class="buy">Buy Now</div>

    $( '#buynow-kore').on( "click", function() {
    var voltage = $( '.kv option:selected').text();
    var hp = $( '.khp option:selected').text();

    var hp15 = "http://www.compressorworld.com/15-hp-rotary-screw-air-compressor-system-230-3-60-total-air-system.html";
    var hp50 = "http://www.compressorworld.com/50-hp-rotary-screw-air-compressors-complete-air-system-lifetime-airend-warranty.html";


    if (voltage == "230" && hp == "15"){
    window.location.href = hp15,"_parent";
    }

    });
```

Basically I'm testing for the selected option and redirecting to the correct page however I also tried to put this into angular I'll show that code below which I don't know how to integrate into the dom.

```
var compressorView = angular.module('AC', [ 'ngRoute','metatags']);


compressorView.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.buy = function () {
    $(function () {
        $scope.$korebuy = $( '#buynow-kore').on( "click", function() {
        var voltage = $( '.kv option:selected').text();
        var hp = $( '.khp option:selected').text();

        var hp15 = "https://www.compressorworld.com/15-hp-rotary-screw-air-compressor-system-230-3-60-total-air-system.html";
        var hp20 = "https://www.compressorworld.com/20-hp-rotary-screw-air-compressors-complete-air-system-lifetime-airend-warranty.html";
        var hp50 = "https://www.compressorworld.com/50-hp-rotary-screw-air-compressors-complete-air-system-lifetime-airend-warranty.html";

        if (voltage == "230" && hp == "15"){
        window.location.href = hp15,"_blank";
        console.log("complete 15");
        }
        if (voltage == "230" && hp == "20"){
        window.location.href = hp20,"_blank";
        console.log("complete 20");
        }
        });
    });
};

$scope.buy();

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/blynn17/ucvn0g3h/

https://jsfiddle.net/blynn17/q7wzvma5/

The jquery code is on a scope but I'm not sure if $korebuy or $scope.buy has to map to `<div  id="buynow-kore" class="buy">Buy Now</div>`

Comment: Forgot use Jquery with Angular. Use directives or don't use Angular.

Comment: I'll look into directives I have the jquery file loaded into my server version I forgot in the fiddle.

Comment: @Michelem is a blanket statement and not entirely correct. You shouldn't use jQuery for DOM interaction in your controller. Bind to a scope value with `ngModel`. Directives are for DOM manipulation and `elem` in your link function will be a jQlite/jQuery object. So his statement to forget jQuery with angular is just wrong, angular provides you with jQuery as standard, you should only use it where angular provides it however, so directives.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of using something like AngularJS is to avoid JQuery, so you should refrain from using them at the same time, and especially combining them.

Instead on your `<div>` you should add `<div id="buynow-kore" ng-click="myFunction">Buy Now</div>`

Then in your controller you should have your code do whatever it is you want:

```
$scope.myFunction = function() { ... set text and stuff ... }
```